# ¿Como insertar varias líneas SQL desde una consulta con un denominador común?

Tags: sql, python, pandas

Quiero insertar varios líneas SQL en una DataFrame python desde una consulta cuyo denominador común haría el EclipseID, el ID de la publicidad. Estoy utilisando MongoDB y Jupyter.

Tenemos una table `eclipse_hashtag` con los id de las publicidades `eclipse_id` y las ID de hashtag `hashtag_id`. Entonces quiero en cada lineas de `eclipse_id` de la DataFrame los `hashtag_id` associados.

Aqui esta la consulta cuando estoy leendola en jupyter :

```
    cur.execute("""
    -- nombre de fois que les personnes ont interragi avec les pubs, 
SELECT eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id,eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id FROM eclipse_hashtag
  GROUP BY eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id, eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id
    ORDER BY eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id,eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id DESC;
    """)
    n = cur.fetchall()
        listado_n = [{"count": elem[0], "eclipse_id": elem[1], "subscriber_id": elem[2]} for elem in n]
```

Y la salida para un ejemplo verificable :

```
EclipseID HashtagID
343513    4210
343513    4135
343513    2410
351651    4135
351651    4247
351651    6518
524752    5138
524752    3312
```

La salida sería de `eclipseid_df.head()` la siguiente :

```
  EclipseID     HashtagID
0 351651      6518|4135|4247
1 343513      4135|2410|4210
2 524752        3312|5138
3  ...             ...
```

Lo hago para hacer un recomendador con factorización de matrices como [Nick Becker, Data Scientist por Enigma, lo hace sobre GitHub](https://beckernick.github.io/matrix-factorization-recommender/).

Pensaba hacer `df_n = pd.DataFrame(listado_n)` pero no me da lo que espero.

Comment: la verdad es que el problema sería bastante más comprensible si utilizaras nombres de tablas y variables más fáciles de leer. Por otra parte, este parece un problema meramente de SQL (¿MySQL probablemente? iría bien añadir la etiqueta), por lo que no sé por qué aparece la etiqueta [tag:python].

Comment: ¿Estás usando [tag:pandas] para leer la tabla SQL? Deberías ayudarnos un poco para que te podamos ayudar. Mete el código que estás usando, metainformación de la/s tabla/s,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tienes un dataframe (llamado `df`) resultado de tu consulta como el que pones en tu ejemplo:

```
   EclipseID  HashtagID
0     343513       4210
1     343513       4135
2     343513       2410
3     351651       4135
4     351651       4247
5     351651       6518
6     524752       5138
7     524752       3312
```

Para agrupar todos los `HashtagID` según su `EclipseID` usa [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). La salida esperada que muestras parece ser una cadena (string) con los `HashtagId` separados por `|`. Otra opción creo que más práctica si vas a trabajar con los datos sería usar una lista Python para agruparlos (o cualquier otro contenedor como un `set`, un array de Numpy o incluso otro DataFrame):

```
df = df.groupby('EclipseID')['HashtagID'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

**Salida:**

> ```
>    EclipseID           HashtagID
> 0     343513  [4210, 4135, 2410]
> 1     351651  [4135, 4247, 6518]
> 2     524752        [5138, 3312]
> ```

Si realmente quieres una cadena, solamente crea una función que haga el trabajo:

```
def cadena(group):
    return '|'.join((str(value).strip() for value in group.values))

df = df.groupby('EclipseID')['HashtagID'].apply(cadena).reset_index()
```

O usando una función lambda (aunque no aporta mucho a lo anterior):

```
df = df.groupby('EclipseID')['HashtagID'].apply(lambda g: '|'.join((str(v).strip() for v in g.values))).reset_index()
```

**Salida:**

> ```
>    EclipseID       HashtagID
> 0     343513  4210|4135|2410
> 1     351651  4135|4247|6518
> 2     524752       5138|3312
> ```

En ambos casos se usa `apply` que lo que hace básicamente es: por cada grupo llamar a una función, pasarle el grupo como argumento y usar su retorno para construir la columna.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre una forma un poco fea desde [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) que, si los datos no son muy grandes, te puede valer:

```
import pandas as pd

df = #### Lee la query como consideres
```

El resultado en el `df` que obtienes es:

```
   EclipseID  HashtagID
0     343513       4210
1     343513       4135
2     343513       2410
3     351651       4135
4     351651       4247
5     351651       6518
6     524752       5138
7     524752       3312
```

Ahora, desde [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), puedes hacer:

```
grupos = df.groupby(df.EclipseID)
eclipseid_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['EclipseID','HashtagID'])
for i, (name, gr) in enumerate(grupos):
    eclipseid_df.loc[i] = [
        name,
        '|'.join(map(str,gr.HashtagID.values))
    ]
```

Cada elemento de la columna `HashtagID` del dataframe `eclipseid_df` sería un *string*:

```
  EclipseID       HashtagID
0    343513  4210|4135|2410
1    351651  4135|4247|6518
2    524752       5138|3312
```

Si se me ocurre una forma un poco menos fea te digo pero deberías trabajar con `groupby` directamente y hacer lo que necesites sobre la columna `HashtagID`. Creo que esa forma sería más 'limpia'.